# wso2 specify access token per application

Tags: oauth, wso2, access-token

In wso2 Application Manager if I log into the ui of the /store module and go to an application registered with that user I can request an access token with a specific duration.
Is it possible to do the same through api?
I'd like tokens for a specific customer to have a different duration

Comment: I believe you're referring to API Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Application Tokens can be generated with different expiry times like this.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials&validity_period=3600" -H "Authorization: Basic XXX" https://localhost:8243/token
```

User tokens have a fixed expiry time, which can be configured in `identity.xml`. See [docs here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Token+API#TokenAPI-Configuringthetokenexpirationtime).

Answer (score -1):

I have tried by passing "validity_period" in token API (as suggested by Bhathiya in his response) but it doesn't work for me (I have used WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 integrated with WSO2 IS), So I have created API to update "[VALIDITY_PERIOD]" column value for "[IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN]" table in the associated database.

You can set any required expiry time in this table.

For more details, you can refer to below link:

https://bhajanmehtablog.wordpress.com/2017/02/01/playing-with-access-oauth-token-for-wso2-api-manager-or-wso2-is/